# Flutter Responsive text

Tags: flutter

I want to use this [flutter_screenutil](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_screenutil) package to get responsive text in my app.

And they require the designSize of my test device. When I go to this site Whatsmyandroid version, I get two values. I get two sizes, the screen size = 720*1600 and css viewport size as 385 * 854? Which one do i use as my designSize?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this](https://github.com/OpenFlutter/flutter_screenutil/issues/235#issuecomment-805594729) GitHub issue;

> Size (360, 690) refers to the size of the device in the UI design
> draft, and the unit is dp. You can fill in the size of the device in
> your own design draft. **Has nothing to do with the actual device size**

The `(360, 690)` refers to `dp`, not actual resolution. For more info; [What is the difference between px, dip, dp, and sp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025282/what-is-the-difference-between-px-dip-dp-and-sp).